# How to override a parent's css property and apply it to a specific child element property?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I set the opacity of `.jumbotron` class to `opacity: 0.9;` and its child elements follow through. How do I set a specific child element to override the parent's property value in this case. I tried using `!important`, `.jumbotron a`, `.jumbotron p + p`, `.jumbotron nth:child(3)`, but none of them work fully. It will change the button to a lower opacity less than 0.9, but not 1, where it's suppose to be solid or in other words show no transparency. Is there maybe another way to get around this problem? Here's the focus code I tried using:

**CSS:**

```
.jumbotron{
        background-color: white;
        color:black;
        opacity:0.9;
        border-radius:0px 0px 10px 10px;
    }
.jumbotron a, .jumbotron p + p, .jumbotron :nth-child(3){
        opacity: 1 !important;
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1 style="color:black;">Welcome!</h1>
  <p>We're an awesome company that creates virtual things for portable devices.</p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button" href="about.html">Learn more</a></p>
</div>
```

**WORKAROUND SOLUTION:**

It appears you cannot override the opacity value to a child's element when the parent's element value is already set. For instance, `.jumbotron` (parent) is set to `opacity:0.9` and `.jumbotron p + p` (2nd p child element)[or whatever else you use to override the value] is set to `opacity: 1 !important` as seen in my above code WILL NOT WORK! Setting it < 1 will work. However, on other css properties such as `color`, `margin`, etc., it will override. With that being said, a workaround is to specifically take the button out of the `.jumbotron` and make a new div with the appropriate css properties as demonstrated below:

```
#divbtn{ 
        position:absolute; /*type of position to freely move the element about*/
        top:290px;
        margin-left:30px;
    }
```

```
<!--opacity cannot be overridden on a child element when the parent's element is set, so I made a new div outside of .jumbotron and make it appear as if it's in .jumbotron without opacity being affected.-->
<div id="divbtn">
   <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button" href="about.html">Learn more</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: caught one thing wrong you should write `:nth-child` while you are writing `nth:child`.. which is totally wrong.

Comment: Thanks for catching that!

Comment: Is it possible to take the button out of jumbotron and position it relatively or absolutely?

Comment: I could try adding another div specifically for the button. I'm try and get back to you.

Comment: @otherDewi I edited my post, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend giving every element inside the jumbotron class a common class. For example, if the class was to be named class_name, then the css would be-

```
.class_name{
            opacity:1;
           }
```

If you didnt understand my answer, or this didnt solve your problem, just comment below.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but the problem is the jumbotron's background will not appear full and will chip it to specific elements which doesn't look nice with space between the elements. So, I need all jumbotron elements including jumbotrons background itself to have opacity except for the button.

Answer (score 0):

The child will always inherit the opacity from its parent. So that means you can't set a different opacity for the child element.

Another solution is instead of using `opacity` you can use `rgba` method.

However here is a workaround method, have a look and may be work for you. Check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/xeqojumo/1/edit)**.

```
.jumbotron{
       background-color: white;
       color:black;
       border-radius:0px 0px 10px 10px;
       position: relative;  
       width:100%;   
    }

.container {   
    position:relative; 
    width:100%;   
}  
.holder {  
    position:absolute;  
    top:0;  
    bottom:0;
    left:0;  
    width:100%;  
    background-color:#FFF;  
    opacity: 0.5;  
    -moz-opacity: 0.5;  
    filter:alpha(opacity=50); 
    z-index:1;

}  
.jumbotron p:last-of-type{ 
    position: relative;  
    width:100%;  
   z-index:2;
   opacity: 1;  
   filter:alpha(opacity=100); 
}
```

Comment: This is a bit complex to understand. Can you tell me what `filter:alpha(opacity=100);` does because I've never seen it before. In general, why you chose to write it like this? I'm curious.

Comment: `filter: alpha(opacity=50);` is used for IE8 and lower versions.

Comment: I see, it's not perfect, but it's near a solution, I notice you layered with extra divs, but then again, the words are not fully blackened thus still being effected with opacity the same way happening for my button.

Comment: if you see the last `p` is not affected by the parent div opacity. As I've already mentioned this is a workaround solution. not perfect answer.

Comment: Right right, but it bothers me that opacity cannot be overridden as other properties can be by simply using `!important` or declaring the right nesting element to change it. I think they should change that to allow us to specify which element has opacity and which doesn't.